# Error de servidor en la aplicación '/' [ASP.NET]

Tags: c#, asp.net, qr

Trato de generar un código QR pero al momento de correr mi aplicación me sale
un error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
>   *El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos.
>
>   Nombre del parámetro: site*

**Seguimiento de pila**:

> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos.
>   Nombre del parámetro: site]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +280
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos.
>   Nombre del parámetro: site]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10042604
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Y en mi **Code Behind** tengo un *TextBox* y un *Button* con el siguiente código:

```
protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QRCodeEncoder enconder = new QRCodeEncoder();       
    Bitmap img = enconder.Encode(txtCode.Text);
    System.Drawing.Image QR = (System.Drawing.Image)img;        

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        QR.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);   
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        imgCtrl.Src = "data:image/gif;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        imgCtrl.Height = 200;
        imgCtrl.Width = 200;
    }
}
```

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar dicho error?
Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que es data:image/gif? ¿No será data:image/jpg o image/png?

Comment: de hecho le cambio a esas extensiones y sigue generando el mismo error.

Comment: ¿En qué línea está el error?

Comment: No me dice en qué línea esta afectando, por eso mi confusión con el error.